# Movie with a scene about how god answered character's prayers

Tags: identify-this-movie

I know this is going to be a tough one but I can't remember anything more and this has been in my mind for a while.

I remember part of a scene where a non-believer (in religion) character (the main one if i recall correctly) returns home after surviving through something dangerous (It might have been a war, I seem to remember that it had been a long time), and someone very close from him (I feel like it was his daughter or his mother), points out how lucky he was that he survived through this and that he should be grateful and it was evidence that God does answer prayers.

And then a dialog somewhat similar to the following takes place:
the main character says "I never prayed for god to get me back home", and the other one answers "I was the one praying"

This is what I remember the most clearly, I'm sorry to say I am not a 100% sure that it was a movie, it might have been in a TV show, sorry.

If I had to give a little more info, I think it was in a movie not too old (so in color). Most movies I watch are in English (It could also be Korean, Japanese, Chinese but less likely).

Comment: This seems like a really cliché thing that you'd see in tons of movies.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is actually an exchange from ***Game of Thrones*** between Davos and his son Matthos.

> **Matthos:** The holy books are much more persuasive than I can be.
>
> **Davos:** I wish I had a god, truly. I'm not mocking you, but I've seen men pray to every god there is, pray for wind, pray for rain, pray for home. None of it works.
>
> **Matthos:** But you always came home.
>
> **Davos:** I wasn't praying.
>
> **Matthos:** But I was.

It's from episode 2 in season 2 [[*The Night Lands*]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Night_Lands). You can see the scene here: